# div style working in Firefox but not IE8

Tags: firefox, html, coding-style, internet-explorer-8

I am creating a banner that resizes to fit the window (I got the code of a blog post) and it works fine in Firefox, but it doesn't display at all in IE8.  Please help!!

```
<html>
<body>

<div style=”position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; left:0px;right:0px;z-index:1”><img src="https://na6.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01580000000pT8r&oid=00D80000000aYeL&lastMod=1273785188000" width=”100%”></div>
<div style=”z-index:2; position:relative; margin:0px; padding:0px;”>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please enter your html correctly.

Comment: can you past a link to broken page?

Comment: @Pekka - I roled your changes back as it could be the ” symbols that are causing the issues.

Comment: Yes the copied " symbols worked with firefox but not in IE8, so replacing them fixed it. Like my answer below suggests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace the utf-8 ” with latin1 "

```
<html>
<body>

<div style="position:relative; width:100%; height:100%; margin:0px; padding:0px; left:0px;right:0px;z-index:1"><img src="https://na6.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01580000000pT8r&oid=00D80000000aYeL&lastMod=1273785188000" width="100%"></div>
<div style="z-index:2; position:relative; margin:0px; padding:0px;">
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Or rather, make sure you save it in the corrent encoding, IE8 plays nice over here

Comment: In notepad, I didn't find the option to save it as latin1.  Just ANSI, Unicode, or Uft-8.

Comment: He's saying use " instead of ”. Try it.

Comment: It worked!!!  I had no idea there were more than one type of quotation mark.  I copied and pasted his code and it worked fine in both IE and Firefox.  I also added the "/" to close the img tag just to be safe.  Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

You've not closed the img tag. It should be as follows:

```
<img src="https://na6.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.ImageServer?id=01580000000pT8r&oid=00D80000000aYeL&lastMod=1273785188000" width=”100%” />
```

I'm guessing this is what's causing the problem. Maybe Firefox is a bit more clever than IE8 at recovering from bad markup.

**EDIT:**

Baloo's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865980/div-style-working-in-firefox-but-not-ie8/2866040#2866040) baffled me at first because I couldn't see what changes he'd suggested, but it appears another user had edited the question and removed those alternative char set speech characters.

Comment: I closed the img tag just like you showed, but it didn't fix it.  I saw on another forum something about height = 100% having trouble in IE, could that be the problem?